# Change image dimensions Matlab 3d image

Tags: matlab

I have af tiff file and i want to change this image dimensions. Is there a easy way to do this?
My problem is that i want to convert af TIFF file from RGB to Indexed using rgb2ind function. It gives me this error:

RGB image has to be M-by-N-by-3 array.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: please show your code/image. It looks like your image is not RGB but rather grayscale. Providing as much information as you can about your problem will help us help you better :)

Comment: @Benoit_11 The OP removed the information about the image size being `1234*1789*4`. The image apparently has an alpha channel.

Comment: yeah sorry i removed the image size but how can i remove the alpha channel ?

Answer (score 0):

If your image has 4 dimensions (eg. RGB + alpha channel), doing this:

```
YourImage(:,:,4) = [];
```

will remove the 4th dimension.